# How can Vue recognize the routes of a link (a tag) in the production?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, routes, hyperlink

I am working in SaaS website and they don't provide a better customization for the website,
so I ended up using the custom HTML & CSS & JS codes to customize the website.

The website is a single page application (SPA) built by Vue, and it uses custom routing

I wanted to change the link of (a tag) by vanilla javascript, it worked, but when I try to click on the link, it redirects me to the original route instead of the link I provided

For example:

This is the original that vue set

```html
<a href="https://example.com/old">OLD</a>
```

and this is the new that I set using vanilla javascript:

```html
<a href="https://example.com/new">NEW</a>
```

it shows the new one in the browser, but when I click on it, it redirects me to the old

how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: The question doesn't have enough details. There's no such problem in general. It's specific to the site in use and whatever affects the way the links are handled

Comment: It is just I want to know how Vue handle routing in production, because Vue now is in production mode, so how vue that is compiled handle routing so I can find a solution for it

Comment: There's no specific info about that. It's supposed to handle it the same as in dev. The rest depends on your case.